# Javascript iteration of JSON Object into an Array for infinte JSON object values

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have a JSON Object with an infinite level of objects inside. I want to frame a JSON Array where it contains the first key in a key and all the associated value in another key.

For eg, The JSON I am having is below,

```
{
    doingnow: {
        "action items": { "open": { "child"....}, "In Progress": { "child"....}, "Completed": { "child"....} },
        "financial": { "q1": { "jan 2017": { "child"... }, "feb 2017": {....} }, q2: {... }, q3: {... },....}
    },
    finished: { "discarded": {... } },
    .........
}
```

But the actual JSON Array which I am expecting

```
[{
    key: "doingnow": children: [{
        key: "action items", children: [{ key: "open", children: [] }, { key: "In Progress", children: [] }, { key: "Completed", children: [] }],
        key: "financial", children: [{ key: q1, children: [{ key: "jan 2017", children: [] }, { key: "feb 2017", children: [] }] },
        { key: q2, children: [{ key: "jan 2017", children: [] }, { key: "feb 2017", children: [] }] }]
    }],
}, { key: "finished", children: [{ ...}] }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Working on it for 2 days. :-(

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: By "infinite", you mean "arbitrary"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a situation where recursion is probably the best choice.

```js
const data = '{doingnow: ... your string ... }'
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(data)

const parseObject = (obj) => {
  let returnArray = []

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    let childrens = []

    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
      childrens = parseObject(obj[key])
    }

    returnArray.push({key: key, children: childrens})
  })
  
  return returnArray
}

const result = parseObject(jsonObject)
```

NB. this should work fine for most object, but you may need some more optimization for huge json objects

Comment: Hi Thank you so much. I got the solution. Much appreciated one. You saved my time. :-)